# Is there a quick way to inject i18n domain into theme/plugin files?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I do have prepared theme files (with __(), and _e(), etc), but they lack domain argument. There are lots of such string scattered around the theme files, editing by hand seems to be a dreadful perspective. Is there any tool to do this quickly? I remember there was a script somewhere, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found what I was looking for - [Marking strings in themes and plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Marking_strings_in_themes_and_plugins). And here is the actual [SVN repository](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/tools/) for tools in question.

Answer (score 1):

There's no perfect solution, because your search would be pretty general. Keyboardshortcuts are a real help in such cases. Ex. Notepad++ [Ctrl] + [F] = search. Then [N] for find and [R] for replace.

Most editors offer search (that includes search&replace) across files (ex. notepad++). You could do a search for `__('`, take a look at the search results list (opens at the exact position with a double click) and then replace `');` with `', MY_TEXTDOMAIN );`

Note: Top of your functions.php should then have something like:
`define( 'MY_TEXTDOMAIN', 'my_textdomain_string' );`
This will hold you away from replaceing everything again, when you decide to change the textdomain string, because it's stored centrally in the Constant MY_TEXTDOMAIN.

Comment: MY_TEXTDOMAIN tip looks handy, thanks. Although I definitely remember there was some script for this.

Comment: I use the same as i wrote above for myself. Dividing it into a child- and parent-theme constant makes even more sense.